# modify CRC field in CAN frame

Tags: python, can-bus

To generate error on CAN, I've done change data field. But It seems just change numerical things. I want to know how to modify CRC field to inject error. Can I change that field with software?.
I want to add some anomalies to corrupt the CRC field of the CAN message.
I used the python can library,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRC is generated by the CAN controller hardware, so you cannot change it from software.

In order to inject errors in CAN frames, you will need a microcontroller which is connected to either the TX line of CANH/CANL and pulls bits to dominant mode when they should be recessive.

Comment: ok, if i use the pcan usb pro can i modify the crc

Comment: @jiji Is it a microcontroller on a custom PCB? If not, then no.